# Getting a unclear graph for a graph data set using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to visualize a graph data set as downloaded from [snap.stanford.edu](http://snap.stanford.edu/) using igraph. Here is what I did:

```
library(igraph)

graph_file = '4.txt'
#Read the data in using igraph
glist<-read.table(graph_file)
gframe <- graph.data.frame(as.data.frame(glist))
plot(gframe)
```

The plot produced from the above code is multilayer and is impossible to visualize anything from it. It looks like:
[image]

Is there something that I am missing? Is there a way I could visually improve this graph?

The graph data set is in the link I mentioned above.

Comment: I usually use k-core decomposition to visualize only the most connected parts of the network in cases like this. I'll try to write an example below.. I see you posted a link to the data.

Comment: @mysteRious Any idea, how to approach this?

Comment: Yes, but even just with the core of the graph plotted, it's still pretty messy. I'll post what I have so you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with k-core decomposition, you can plot the subset of the nodes that are most tightly connected to one another, and it helps a lot in terms of being able to see important elements of the structure. For this dataset, not so much, but here's how to go through the process:

```
> library(igraph)
> con <- gzcon(url("http://snap.stanford.edu/data/p2p-Gnutella04.txt.gz"))
> txt <- readLines(con)
> edgelist <- strsplit(txt[5:39998],"\t")
> m <- matrix(unlist(edgelist),nc=2,byrow=TRUE)
> g <- graph.data.frame(m)
> coreness <- graph.coreness(g)
```

Find max number of connections:

```
> max(V(g)$core)
[1] 7
```

Then plot:

```
> kcore <- induced.subgraph(graph=g,vids=which(coreness>6))
> plot(kcore)
```

Yuck:

[image: still terrible]

To plot the ego network around a particular node:

```
> g3109 <- make_ego_graph(g, 1, "3109")
> plot(g3109[[1]], asp=0)
```

[image: igraph better]

Comment: May be I will try with a subset of this graph

Comment: I'm going to keep playing with it too. Now this is bugging me :)

Comment: Is there also a way to single out one node? For example a node with maximum degree?

Comment: Yes: `V(g)$name[degree(g)==max(degree(g))]` gives node `3109` in this network.

Comment: Yeah, is there a way to only plot this node?